# Как разрешить ввод в текстовое поле только вещественных чисел?

Tags: c#, wpf

Как разрешить ввод в текстовое поле только вещественных чисел с использованием региональных параметров. Т.е., чтобы можно было ввести и точку, и запятую.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Использовать [Int32.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/f56zcx39.aspx). Заготовка:

```
private void TextBox_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
    try {
        number = Int32.Parse(e.Text, culture.NumberFormat);
        e.Handled = true;    
    }
    catch(FormatException) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант можно запретить все символы кроме цифр. Пример отсечения латинских символов.
Внутри события нажатия кнопки:

```
if ((e.KeyChar >= 'A') && (e.KeyChar <= 'z'))
{
    e.Handled = true;  // не вводим нажатый символ в поле
    MessageBox.Show("Введён латинский символ", "Ошибка", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);   //выводим сообщение об ошибке
}
```

Comment: e.KeyChar в WPF нет.

Comment: И в первом и во втором случае я получу целое число на выходе. А как получить вещественное без ввода букв и других символов с возможностью ввода точки, запятой и минуса?

Comment: Может маска? http://www.sql.ru/forum/actualthread.aspx?tid=693983

Comment: А есть ли другой способ без маски допустим с помощью регулярных выражений?