# Текстовое поле только для чисел

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, wpf-toolkit

Перепробовал уже очень много способов, несколько часов гуглежа.. результат ноль.

xctk:IntegerUpDown и другие updown в этой либе свободно позволяют писать текст в них кроме чисел, просто выключая кнопки UpDown;

[ещё способ](https://programmingistheway.wordpress.com/2017/02/17/only-numbers-in-a-wpf-textbox-with-regular-expressions/), он вроде бы не плохой, но позволяет вставить обычный текст на ctrl + v;

Comment: [How do I get a TextBox to only accept numeric input in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1268648/312041)

Comment: tym32167, спасибо Вам, но я вчера этот пример уже смотрел, он тоже работал плохо, уже не помню почему конкретно

Comment: ну как вспомните, обновите вопрос

Comment: А что плохого в том, что в поле для ввода чисел можно ввести всё что угодно? В WPF есть валидация привязанных данных: https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/14.php

Comment: tym32167, как-то получилось промотать незаметно до
[этого](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12721673/10882408), который находился прямо под ним.
Однако сейчас, кажется, я уже нашёл за что зацепиться.

Comment: Dmitriy Zagorulkin, плохо то, что приходится потом обрабатывать этот тест и писать пользователю о том, что он написал не то, что от него требовалось. Это лишние дейсвия. Проще сделать так, чтобы пользователь при своей попытке написать не то, что от него требуется, сразу понял, что это писать не надо.

Comment: **валидация** - это очень даже не плохо, ни разу на неё не натыкался, пригодится где-нибудь в другом месте, спасибо за это, но в конкретном случае я не хочу убеждаться в правильности, я хочу убеждать пользователей как делать правильно)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо давайте [Андрею](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/218063/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9-nop) с его [вариантом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/802906/344075), в котором я доработал Pasting:

```
private void Pasting(object sender, DataObjectPastingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.DataObject.GetDataPresent(typeof(string)))
    {
        var pastedText = (string)e.DataObject.GetData(typeof(string));
        DataObject dataObject = new DataObject();
        dataObject.SetText(GetValidInput(pastedText));
        e.DataObject = dataObject;
        return;
    }
    e.CancelCommand();
}
private string GetValidInput(string Input)
{
    return Regex.Replace(Input, @"[^0-9]", "");
}
```

(И ещё немного по мелочам). Это лучший из вариантов реализации TextBox с ограниченным вводом из всех, что я встречал.

Но до этого, посмотрев на [этот вариант](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/108095/344075), сделал это (работает нормально, не надо заморачиваться со всякими классами, но вариант выше лучше):

```
private static int LastSelectionStart;
private static string LastText;
private void InputTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (InputTextBox.Text.Length > 0)
    {
        if (!Int32.TryParse(InputTextBox.Text, out int Int)) //тут можно установить ограничение по макс. размеру от байт до шорт, может даже можно бигинт припилить; ещё можно просто ограничение припилить с помощью out'а у трайпарсе
        {
            InputTextBox.Text = LastText;
            InputTextBox.SelectionStart = LastSelectionStart;
        }
        else LastText = InputTextBox.Text;
    }
    else LastText = "";
}
private void InputTextBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    LastSelectionStart = InputTextBox.SelectionStart;
}
```

Однако этот вариант, в отличие от варианта выше, как вариант Андрея с его пастингом, при вставке из буфера не фильтрует, а только проверяет текст на наличие не-цифр и в случае их присутствия не пропускает весь вставленный текст.

Comment: Смотрите ответ-дубликат, там готовая реализация. Судя по [информации на MSDN](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.dataobjectpastingeventargs.dataobject), можно переписать значение `e.DataObject` на своё и тогда будут вставлены эти новые данные, а не исходные. Если не получится — напишите комментарий под моим ответом там, я дополню ответ.

Comment: Вы пробовали тот класс в его текущем виде скопировать к себе в проект и добавить в окно? Ничего дописывать не надо, надо будет только потом подправить IsValidInput

Comment: Я вас не понимаю. Вы не знаете как добавить этот контрол в xaml или что?

Comment: Нет, вам не нужен UserControl, вам нужно просто добавить пространство имен в XAML, например, если этот класс лежит в одной папке с MainWindow, то вы можете его добавить как `<local:HexTextBox ... />`, если в другой папке, то вы должны объявить пространство имен по аналогии с `local`

Comment: Спасибо у нас принято говорить голосованием за ответ (слева есть стрелочки) :)